# Query ORA-01791 Error due to ||','||

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression when I try to run this query. I am able to run it when the SELECT is comma seperated (AH.NAME, REPLACE(A.ACTIVE_DC,',','/'),etc) but with the ||','|| I am not able to get it to work. How can I get this query to run? Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    AH.NAME_1||','||
    REPLACE(A.ACTIVE_DC,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(A.PASSIVE_DC,',','/')||','||    
    REPLACE(H.ENVIRONMENT,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x')||','||
    H.FULL_NAME||','||
    H.PRIMARY_IP||','||
    H.COMPLIANCE||','||
    H.OS
FROM
    HOST H
FULL OUTER JOIN
    APP_HOST AH ON
        AH.ID_2 = H.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN
    HOST_SVR HS ON
        HS.ID_1 = H.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    APP A ON
        AH.ID_1 = A.ID          
FULL OUTER JOIN
    SVR S ON
        HS.ID_2 = S.ID     
WHERE S.NAME IS NOT NULL     
ORDER BY
    AH.NAME_1,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x'),
    H.FULL_NAME
```

Comment: Try it without the order by.

Comment: It'll work without the ORDER BY but that is necessary as this is a report and without it there are 15,000 rows of chaos. That is the part I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I know.  My comment was just trying to trigger an "OH! I see".  Sorry about that; I gave an answer below, as did someone else with a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you aren't trying to order in the sequence the fields appear in the concatenation, you can't just `order by 1` or repeat the whole string. You can use a subquery though:

```
SELECT RESULT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT AH.NAME_1,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x') AS NAME,
        H.FULL_NAME,
        AH.NAME_1||','||
        REPLACE(A.ACTIVE_DC,',','/')||','||
        REPLACE(A.PASSIVE_DC,',','/')||','||    
        REPLACE(H.ENVIRONMENT,',','/')||','||
        REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x')||','||
        H.FULL_NAME||','||
        H.PRIMARY_IP||','||
        H.COMPLIANCE||','||
        H.OS AS RESULT
    FROM
        HOST H
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        APP_HOST AH ON
            AH.ID_2 = H.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        HOST_SVR HS ON
            HS.ID_1 = H.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
        APP A ON
            AH.ID_1 = A.ID          
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        SVR S ON
            HS.ID_2 = S.ID     
    WHERE S.NAME IS NOT NULL     
)
ORDER BY
    NAME_1,
    NAME,
    FULL_NAME
```

Comment: @Alex_Poole Because of `distinct` you can't `order by` by field not in result set. With current version of answer you got same error as in question. SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12300

Comment: @ThinkJet - thanks, I'd noticed that and hdd already moved the distinct back inside the subquery (like [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12298)). I had it inside and moved it out, not sure why; think I briefly thought the other fields in the concatenation would become indistinct (!?), but it's OK... I think...

Answer (score 1):

You need to place complex expression from `select` part to `order by` part or on the contrary add `REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x')` expression to selection list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    AH.NAME||','||
    REPLACE(A.ACTIVE_DC,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(A.PASSIVE_DC,',','/')||','||    
    REPLACE(H.ENVIRONMENT,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x')||','||
    H.FULL_NAME||','||
    H.PRIMARY_IP||','||
    H.COMPLIANCE||','||
    H.OS
FROM
    HOST H
FULL OUTER JOIN
    APP_HOST AH ON
        AH.ID_2 = H.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN
    HOST_SVR HS ON
        HS.ID_1 = H.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    APP A ON
        AH.ID_1 = A.ID          
FULL OUTER JOIN
    SVR S ON
        HS.ID_2 = S.ID     
WHERE S.NAME IS NOT NULL     
ORDER BY
    -- same as selected
    AH.NAME||','||
    REPLACE(A.ACTIVE_DC,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(A.PASSIVE_DC,',','/')||','||    
    REPLACE(H.ENVIRONMENT,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x')||','||
    H.FULL_NAME||','||
    H.PRIMARY_IP||','||
    H.COMPLIANCE||','||
    H.OS
```

Query above produce wrong result from task's point of view because sorting order differs from initial query.

So use 2nd option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    AH.NAME||','||
    REPLACE(A.ACTIVE_DC,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(A.PASSIVE_DC,',','/')||','||    
    REPLACE(H.ENVIRONMENT,',','/')||','||
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x')||','||
    H.FULL_NAME||','||
    H.PRIMARY_IP||','||
    H.COMPLIANCE||','||
    H.OS,
    -- next from order by
    AH.NAME_1,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x'),
    H.FULL_NAME
FROM
    HOST H
FULL OUTER JOIN
    APP_HOST AH ON
        AH.ID_2 = H.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN
    HOST_SVR HS ON
        HS.ID_1 = H.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    APP A ON
        AH.ID_1 = A.ID          
FULL OUTER JOIN
    SVR S ON
        HS.ID_2 = S.ID     
WHERE S.NAME IS NOT NULL     
ORDER BY
    AH.NAME_1,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x'),
    H.FULL_NAME
```

Second variant works because all `order by` expressions included into constructed string and can't produce more distinct values than at initial variant.

But if you want to produce result set with only one field, then you must do that in 2 steps with subquery: on first step distinct, on second - sort without distinct:

```
  select 
    full_string
  from (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        (
          AH.NAME||','||
          REPLACE(A.ACTIVE_DC,',','/')||','||
          REPLACE(A.PASSIVE_DC,',','/')||','||    
          REPLACE(H.ENVIRONMENT,',','/')||','||
          REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x')||','||
          H.FULL_NAME||','||
          H.PRIMARY_IP||','||
          H.COMPLIANCE||','||
          H.OS
        ) as full_string,
        -- next from order by
        AH.NAME_1,
        REPLACE(REPLACE(S.NAME,',','-'),'_x','-x') S_NAME_REPLACE,
        H.FULL_NAME,
    FROM
        HOST H
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        APP_HOST AH ON
            AH.ID_2 = H.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        HOST_SVR HS ON
            HS.ID_1 = H.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
        APP A ON
            AH.ID_1 = A.ID          
    FULL OUTER JOIN
        SVR S ON
            HS.ID_2 = S.ID     
    WHERE S.NAME IS NOT NULL     
  )
  ORDER BY
      NAME_1,
      S_NAME_REPLACE,
      FULL_NAME
```

It works because there are no aggregate expression in final query.

Illustration for that can be found at [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12305).

Comment: The second approach would work (and be a bit simpler) if the client chose to ignore the other columns. Obviously we don't know the client but I'm guessing it's SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer), largely because you could do the concatenation later if it was JDBC or whatever. If so then `column name_1 noprint` etc. would give the desired output.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, you are right, but there are more possibilities. E.g. some variant of custom reporting engine which unloads generic set of query results to Excel or comma-separated-values file. Even more, based on concatenation format and excluding commas from field values, it's  a pretty good chance for CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I would try performing the distinct, joins and order by in an inline view (subquery) and letting the concatanation  happen in the master query.

Answer (score 0):

Without the string concatenation, your query is selecting many columns, and those columns appear in the order by clause.

With the concatenation, you are "selecting" only one column, and you are using a distinct.  You can only order by columns which appear in a select distinct! The reason for this is that when you do a select distinct you might "merge" a bunch of rows for which clauses in an order by might actually be different.

**EDIT**: That's the reason for the error, at any rate; I see someone else has already answered your question of how to get it to run.